# Issues while testing the server using telnet

Tags: java, telnet

I am testing whether the server is working or not in command prompt, so I used

telnet host port

I will recieve message as

```
220 Unauthorized use is prohibited
```

and the cursor just blank

and after 4-5mins

```
471 7.7.0 Timeout waiting for client input
connection to the host lost
```

Does it mean I dont have access or I got access. Basically I am trying to read emails from microsoft exchange server through java program. If I debug from java program I will recieve error below

```
Connection refused
```

While I am able to send the mail using these two statements

```
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "host");
props.put("mail.from", "username@domain.co.uk");
```

It doesn't ask for port or password.

If I do this way

```
props.setProperty("mail.imap.auth.disable","true");
Store store = session.getStore("imap");
store.connect(host,25,username, password);//password=windows password to login in
```

after debug

```
EBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.3
DEBUG: getProvider() returning  
javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
DEBUG: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG: disable AUTH=PLAIN
DEBUG: trying to connect to host "host", port 25, isSSL false
220 Unauthorized use prohibited
javax.mail.MessagingException: 220 Unauthorized use prohibited;
nested exception is:

com.sun.mail.iap.ConnectionException: 220 Unauthorized use prohibited
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:616)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:291)
at TestMail.InboxReader.main(InboxReader.java:52)

Caused by: com.sun.mail.iap.ConnectionException: 220 Unauthorized use prohibited
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.processGreeting(IMAPProtocol.java:230)
at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:116)
at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:104)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:585)
... 2 more
Java Result: 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messages you got from telnet mean that you successfully connected to your server, so your IP and port are correct and server is up and running.  Strings `220 Unauthorized use is prohibited` and `471 7.7.0 Timeout waiting for client input` contain text sent to you by server.  String `connection to the host lost` is a notification from `telnet` about the fact, that server closed connection from its side.

Message `Connection refused` means that host is up and running, but there are no processes on the host that listen on port you specified.  This may mean that your host name points not to the host where server is running, or your port is incorrect.

Comment: This time I update my code   session.getStore("imap"); and store.connect(host, 25, username, password); by doing this I have recieved the exception as "220 Unauthorized use prohibited" and program stopped.